# PHP and MySql beginner

Tags: php, mysql

HI I am a beginer web developer and for the past 6 months I have learned XHTML/CSS/Javascript/jQuery, before that I did about 3 months of Java witch resulted in a Monopoly game but that is all the programming experience I have .

Now I am thinking of starting to learn PHP and MySql.There seems to be tons of research on the internet about each of them but my problem is that I don't know where to beging and witch book to first read in order to fully master the 2 technologies.

Should I first learn MySql or PHP?

What I want is if someone can recomend me an up to date book or 2 that someone in my position should start reading for both of the 2 technologies and after a beginner book and a bit of practice what else should I read in order to fully master them?

I know learning a programming language is done over the years and with alot of practice but I found that learning javascript and jQUery was alot easier after a friend of mine told me exactly witch books helped him learn them and not to start reading tons of books and not finishing them because I couldent find the needed information (this was the reason in my case for stoping to further learn java )

I should mension that I have no previous database experince im a bit confuse on the diferences on SQL , MySql ,Sql-Server , NoSql but it seems that everything I read about PHP goes head to head with MySql so I am thinking it's a good start.

Edited: It seems most people miseunderstand what I wanted.What I want was if someone could post a path to learning PHP with books or resources for each thing for example if you want to build a CMS read this book or an e-commerce websites read this book or resoruce etc.

Comment: [may read this](http://www.elcaro-guide.com/php-blog/basics-for-php-beginners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a popular and effective technology stack, so there are some decent books on the subject.  You might be able to get a short free trial on safaribooksonline.com (O'Reilly's web site) and take a look at which one most appeals to you.  Here are a couple of books to look at.

Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript
By: Robin Nixon
Publisher: O'Reilly Media, Inc.
Print ISBN-13: 978-0-596-15713-5

Head First PHP & MySQL
By: Lynn Beighley; Michael Morrison
Publisher: O'Reilly Media, Inc.
Print ISBN-13: 978-0-596-00630-3

Some public libraries have these books as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should start with http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp :). After you will reach some knowledges, it will help you to work with database(db).

Comment: sure? tell me why? it isn't good a good point to start? doesn't it help you to gain some basic knowledges about prog. lang.?

Comment: If you start learning with an incorrect resource it is hard to learn it the correct way afterwards. The tutorial from #php in Quakenet has afaik a high quality: http://tut.php-quake.net/en/

Comment: 1. w3schools is fine for starting #alotofpeopleondifferentsites
2. Even this site has many lacks, it's a good point to start, because it acknowledges you with the basics in a simple way. For those who want to move to an advanced level, should try php.net

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples on php.net.
I would recommend to learn PHP and MySQL at the same time.
The two match perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start with PHP. since mysql is pretty simpel at the start, pretty clean english :-)

get WAMP if on windows, or LAMP if on Linux. there you will have phpmyadmin, that is a php based mysql administration webgui, very straight forward.

you can add my to skype, where im avaible all weekdays if you have any questions about php or mysql. my skype is m@rcus.brun$ten. Where @ = a and $ = s. 
PHP is pretty simple, you should be on your feet within days (if you have any programming skills :-) )

Comment: As I have mentioned my only programming experience is a Monopoly game in Java and a couple of script using mostly jQuery

Comment: Then PHP is a childsplay

Answer (score 0):

MySQL <> PHP.

That is, MySQL is an RDBMS and PHP is some web monkey client language.

- PHP can connect to a variety of DBMS backend whether relational or NoSQL
- MySQL can have client apps in any language that has MySQL drivers/connectors

You can learn either or both.

I'd also suggest you ensure you are proficient in your current languages because language is irrelevant if you can actually *program*

Answer (score 0):

For PHP&MySql (beginner level) I would recommend the excellent (free) book: [Practical PHP](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp) . 
Also, for a "healthy" start, please read the PHP security book: http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/.

Answer (score 0):

the book I liked best in the begining was PHP Object-Oriented Solutions by David Powers and I also live and die by the PHP manual. I got windows help file version.
[PHP Manual CHM file](http://www.php.net/download-docs.php)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the same path I took. I learned a little about php syntax, and then I did some tutorial already working wtih MVC Frameworks. I recommend this, [CodeIgniter From Scratch: Day 1.](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/)

It's pretty easy to understand even if you know little about php/mySql, and it will also get you used to MVC programming, and using a framework.