# How to display stored url in database to a webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to PHP and MySQL. I've created a form that uploads a url to my database field and I would like to know how to display the stored url from the  database to a webpage.

Comment: Have you used GOOGLE?

Comment: yes ,but i have seen this site yesterday so i found easy to ask queryand get solved

Comment: You should use a tutorial somewhere. This website is meant to be for debugging problems, and errors, rather than telling people how to do things in the first place. As a direct answer, you need to include a database connection in your PHP, and then fetch the database contents as an array that you can then use to echo out on your page.

Comment: And please improve english , as there are future users too who will read Q & Answers!

Comment: @jogesh_pi: I don't think that is a helpful comment - if someone has problems with their English, can't you edit the question to make it more readable and improve clarity rather than sniping at the first-time user?

Comment: In my opinion also you should read about PHP and MySQL programming first. I recommend the book [Teach yourself PHP in 24 hours](http://books.google.hu/books/about/Sams_Teach_Yourself_PHP_in_24_Hours.html?id=xFs6JpC6HNIC&redir_esc=y) which has been translated into several languages too. But you can find good tutorials on the net also. Also, there are a lot of security risk in a web-based database application that you should learn and care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we don't know your database structure or the used PHP library, I assume that you can select the stored information into an array like this:

```
$row['URL'] = 'your stored url';
```

Then you can easily print it out using more formulas:

```
<?php print('<a href="'.$row['URL'].'">Click here</a>'); ?>
```

Or if you want to integrate php only for the url printing:

```
<a href="<?php print($row['URL']); ?>">Click here</a>
```

Basically the two is identical, but if you have a large HTML and minimal PHP, then the second solution would be easier to edit and maintain.

Answer (score 4):

Like this

```
$query = "SELECT url FROM table";
$resource = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($resource) > 0) {
    $results = array();
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($resource)) {
        $results[] = $record;
    }
}

foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result['url'];
}
```

And if you are among the mysql_* complain group:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT url FROM table";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    // Loop through results
    $results = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    $result->free();
}

foreach ($results as $r) {
    echo $r['url'];
}

$mysqli->close();
```

***Edit*** I would like to add that it would not be a bad idea to first consult a beginners PHP/MySQL book and get yourself up to speed with the programming basics.

#### Resource

[PHP Beginner books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953335/php-and-mysql-beginner)

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated and having lots of Security holes .Either use `mysqli` Or `PDO`.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Do you use a bot for these kinds of things :) read my answer!

Comment: jack, `but my PHP version is still 5.3.3 ` . Its your fault ,if future visitors are not getting good/proper answer here then there is no point in posting deprecated syntax.You may be using 5.3 but what if I use 5.6 version ? You can still edit and use `mysqli`.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com There you go

Comment: Thanks ! :) Now it seems good.